# Change styles & size of Google's "I'm not a robot" ReCaptcha V2

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

So many threads about not being able to change the styles (background-color, text color...) of Googles ReCaptcha. However, less than 2 weeks ago I visited the website of Spotify.com and at the Sign Up page, I saw the official ReCaptcha with a dark background, white text and same blue and gray logo.

A day after, I wanted to change the styles of the ReCaptcha on my website, so I went to Spotify.com to check how they did it. Unfortunately, they changed the Sign Up page or they moved it or whatever. I am sure it is possible in some way, but I'm too inexperienced to find out how myself. I found something on Google Developers mentioning "theme": https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param. Furthermore, it says something about size.

How do I change the styles and size of Google's official "I'm not a robot" ReCaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

reCAPTCHA V2 allows you to change the theme of the rendered captcha, perhaps they were using the "dark" theme. Here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

So for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var onloadCallback = function() {
   grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
     'data-theme' : 'dark'
   });
 };
</script>
```

Comment: I currently have the ReCaptcha as follows:
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."></div>
But now what do I fill in at "html_element"?

Comment: If you are doing this inline, then just add `data-theme="dark"` to your element (e.g. `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="..."></div>`).